# Product of regular field and computed field in an ORDER BY clause

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

The following query works fine:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table_b WHERE field_a = p.a) AS d
FROM table_a AS p
ORDER BY b DESC
```

And this also works:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table_b WHERE field_a = p.a) AS d
FROM table_a AS p
ORDER BY d DESC
```

But the following produces a `ERROR; column 'd' does not exist` error:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table_b WHERE field_a = p.a) AS d
FROM table_a AS p
ORDER BY (b * d) DESC
```

Only difference between the three queries above is the `ORDER BY` clause. In the first two queries, results are ordered by either the `b` field or by the dynamic `d` field. In the last query, results are (should be) ordered by the product of `b` times `d`.

How comes, in the last query, PostgreSQL says that `d` does not exist while it can find it without issue in the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary expressions in the [`order by` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) can only be formed from **input columns**:

> Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values.

You will need to subquery it:

```
select *
from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) s
order by a * b
```